# configure: error: linking to Fortran libraries from C fails

Tags: compiling, libraries, c, configure, fortran

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5OJrU_gQJE) to install the mentioned software (called PRESTO), but when I type `./configure`, I receive the following message:

```
checking how to get verbose linking output from /home/user/Softwares/iraf/unix/hlib//f77.sh... -v
checking for Fortran 77 libraries of /home/user/Softwares/iraf/unix/hlib//f77.sh...  -lf2c
checking for dummy main to link with Fortran 77 libraries... unknown
configure: error: in `/home/user/Softwares/tempo':
configure: error: linking to Fortran libraries from C fails
See `config.log' for more details
```

I have tried to google the error but not really much is reported about it. Any suggested workaround ?

EDIT: [here the log file](https://pastebin.com/knb2hL3D) (too long to attach it here).

EDIT2: Here some useful output:

```
~/Softwares/tempo$ echo $F77
/home/user/Softwares/iraf/unix/hlib//f77.sh
(base) user@user:~/Softwares/tempo$ type -a f77
f77 is /usr/bin/f77
f77 is /usr/bin/f77
```

Comment: Did you check "config.log" for "more details"..?  If it provided no "useful" details, you should check if "configure --help" gives you anything that will help...

Comment: I did not spot anything particularly enlightening in the log file. I pastebin it here.

Comment: Is this the software? https://prestosql.io/ If so, there is no need to configure or build, just unpack the tar.gz and you can use it right away, is already compiled as [explained in the documentation](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html). if it not the right software, please provide a link to the software you are trying to install.

Comment: Nope, sorry! I was sure I had linked it in the message. I'll do it now.

Comment: Maybe this page is relevant [The Carnegie Supernova Project - Frequently Asked Questions](https://csp.obs.carnegiescience.edu/data/snpy/FAQ)? in particular the section **I get error messages about fortran compilers and it seems to be trying to use /.../iraf/iraf/unix/hlib/f77.sh. IRAF? Seriously?**

Comment: @steeldriver, I do not see really how... could you please tell me more?

Comment: (sorry I don't have the patience to watch a video tutorial) really I was just questioning why `./configure` was choosing the IRAF `f77.sh` wrapper - rather than a "normal" Fortran compiler such as `gfortran`. Is that intentional - or just because other software on your system has configured your environment to prefer the `IRAF` compiler?

Comment: @steeldriver, that's a good question! I do not have the knowledge to spot those "details"... If you could guide me to know more about that, it could be a step towards the solution.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the outputs of `echo $F77` and `type -a f77`

Comment: @steeldriver, done. It seems you were right with the IRAF compiler (although I do not know what that implies)

Comment: OK so I'd suggest trying either `./configure F77=` (re-assigning an empty value to the variable) or `./configure F77=/usr/bin/f77` (re-assigning it explicitly)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks! I am going to try it soon. But before: the command before `./configure` was `./prepare`. Does that have anything to do/to change with F77? In other words: do I need to re-run `./prepare F77=/usr/bin/F77`?

Comment: Sorry - I don't know. You could possibly execute `export F77=/usr/bin/f77` right at the start instead.

Comment: Well, at least this seems to be gone through! If you write an answer, I will be glad to accept it. Thanks

Comment: @steeldriver, also I opened another thread [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179817/error-expected-a-right-parenthesis-in-expression-at-1-after-make-command] (to solve a related issue, if you can give it a look)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99726/discussion-between-py-ser-and-steeldriver).