# Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1) after `make` command

Tags: command-line, compiling, make, configure, fortran

I am compiling a software following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5OJrU_gQJE) (called PRESTO), but when I type `./configure`, I receive the following message:

```
$ make && sudo make install
Making all in src
make[1]: enter directory "/home/user/Softwares/tempo/src"
/usr/bin/f77  -g -O2 -c -o bnryddfwhiecc.o bnryddfwhiecc.f
bnryddfwhiecc.f:130:71: Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)
Makefile:468: set of instructions for the objective "bnryddfwhiecc.o" failed 
make[1]: *** [bnryddfwhiecc.o] Error 1
make[1]: exit directory "/home/user/Softwares/tempo/src"
Makefile:359: set of instructions for the objective "all-recursive" failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Errore 1
```

I believe it has to do with the excessive length of the lines in the code. I have tried to add a `&` character to the sixth column of the "following" line, or right after the end of the long line, basically [what is said here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5OJrU_gQJE), but did not work.

I would rather use a command to disable the long-lines errors, instead of going to modify each line of each file. But I do not know enough to take actions.

Comment: @dadexix86, that post is mine too. It is quite different matter.

Comment: To me it looks like the same issue, you are trying to install a program following a tutorial and various errors popup that stops you from doing it. But I retract my vote since you are confident that the two are not related. On a related note, you put the wrong link to the tutorial here. Also, you might want to send an email to the author of that tutorial, as said in its first line, it might be more effective :)

Comment: Different errors, different threads. One was about compiler settings, this one is .f contents. I have already written an email to the tutorial author even before starting the previous thread. Thank you for retracting your vote. If you know enough to believe they are the same issue, maybe you even know just a bit to share that can help me too?

Comment: I never installed this program myself, but to me this problem still looks related to the other one and its solution. I think that someone more expert like @steeldriver should have a look at it (maybe put a link there to this conversation). You should configure the build with the option to use extended lines (see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vn6l/index.html#c40001c6200a ), but I have sincerely no idea how to do that.

Comment: @dadexix86, if you could make an answer to write exactly where I should put the `-e` option (during the `make`, or the `./configure`?) it would be great and I would be glad to accept it, if it works!

Comment: No, I cannot, because I do not know. What I can tell you is that in the linked tutorial they are using gfortran and not f77 to compile. Maybe you can restart from 0, re-follow the instructions from the previous post and use gfortran instead of f77 (and you see in the video that the option to ignore the fixed line lenght is automatically used)

Comment: I do not know how to use gfortran instead of f77, and I do not know how you can tell that in the video they use the option to ignore the fixed length. You say that "you don't know", yet you flagged my post for closing?

Comment: For me, this is a problem of the configure command, that's why I flagged it as a duplicate of the other post in which a configuration problem was solved. I am strongly confident that asking for help in the other post will help you solve this problem too. You protested and I then removed the flag and I am trying to help. You don't like it? No problem. Good luck with it.

Comment: @dadexix86 I agree that starting over is a good idea - my *guess* is that the OP has a more significantly modified build environment (we already rooted out an inappropriate `F77` variable, but who knows what others are lurking). FWIW when I attempt to build `tempo`, the Fortran compile line it generates is `gfortran  -g -O2 -ffixed-form -ffixed-line-length-none -std=legacy -c -o bnryddfwhiecc.o bnryddfwhiecc.f`. Maybe executing `./configure` in a completely bare environment would work? Ex. `env -i ./configure` and `env -i make`?

Comment: @steeldriver thanks. I am not sure I am following... In any case, I tried `env -i ./configure`, and I got the following error: 
`checking whether the C compiler works... no ;
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`

Comment: @Py-ser oops my bad - that environment is TOO bare: try `env -i PATH=$PATH ./configure`

Comment: It went through! Once again, if you would write an answer (possibly with more details so that I actually can get a grasp of what I am doing...) I will be glad to accept it! thanks

Comment: @steeldriver, please let's continue this discussion [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99726/discussion-between-py-ser-and-steeldriver)